# Telerik dropdownlist does not seem to bind to JSON

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, kendo-dropdown

I try to populate the dropdownlist from my database. When loading the view, the dropdownlist spinner appears to do something , then the spinner vanishes and the droplist is empty? Can someone propose a solution. Cheers.

QLine.cs

```
public partial class QLine
    {
        [Key]
        public int lineId { get; set; }

        public int networkId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string lineName { get; set; }

        public virtual QNetwork QNetwork { get; set; }
    }
```

LinesDroplistController.cs

```
public class LinesDroplistController : Controller
    {
        private KprModel db = new KprModel();

        public JsonResult GetMLines()
            {
            var result = db.QLines.Where(abc => abc.networkId == 1);
            return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            } 
     }
```

myView.cshtml

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
.Name("LineDropDownList") 
.DataTextField("lineName") 
.DataValueField("lineId") 
.AutoBind(true)
.DataSource(source =>
 {
  source.Read(read =>
  {
   read.Action("GetMLines", "LinesDroplist"); 
   });
  })
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
source.Read(read =>
{
    read.Action("GetMLines", "LinesDroplist")
}).ServerFiltering(true);
```

**When the serverFiltering is disabled, then the combobox will not make any additional requests to the server.**

Comment: Thanks, I tried your suggestion, but it did not work. I think my result is returning a complex model due to having virtual link in the Qline class.

Answer (score 0):

It worked when changing

```
var result = db.QLines.Where(abc => abc.networkId == 1);
```

to

```
var result = db.QLines.Where(abc => abc.networkId == 1).Select(x => new { x.lineName, x.lineId });
```